# How can I keep this random code to keep the same odds but change from 100 items to 125? It still needs to be the same percentage as the 100

Tags: vb.net

I have this code and everything is working just fine. The code was figured for 100 items but now that has changed to 125 items. I need the code to keep the same percentage odds at random but with 125 instead of 100. Can anyone help explain exactly what this code is doing so I will know if the items ever change again that I will know what to do next time? Thank you!

```
For i As Integer = 0 To positions.Length - 1
        Dim p As Integer = rndItems.Next(100)

        If p < 90 Then
            positions(i) = p \ 15
        ElseIf p < 94 Then
            positions(i) = 6
        ElseIf p < 98 Then
            positions(i) = 7
        Else
            positions(i) = 8
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You mean the number of items in `positions`? Then you don't need to change anything.

Comment: Nico, are you saying that if i change rndItems.Next(100) to rndItems.Next(125) then I do not need to change anything else and the results will still be the same random percentage?

Comment: No, I'm not. Why do you want to change the `rndItems.Next(100)`?

Comment: because the items have changed now and I have 125 instead of 100 but i still need the odds/percentage to still be the same as it was when i only had 100 items.

Comment: What items? The algorithm will return numbers between 0 and 8 (no 100 here). And the number of items in `positions` does not affect the algorithm at all.

Comment: ok i guess what i am saying or trying to do is... i need the number 8 to not show up as much as it is doing right now. do i just need to chane the p< 90, p<94, and p<98 to something else? and keep the rndItems.next to 100?

Comment: Ah, I see. Right now, the probability of 8 is 2%. You can get down to 1% by changing the thresholds. If you need finer control, you need to change the `.Next(100)`, indeed. But I would suggest `1000` to keep things simple.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification. changing the thresholds and changing .next to 1000 works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question as worded is not entirely clear, so my answer is based on my interpretation of what you're asking for. Adding some clarification in your question would be helpful.

Think of it this way: your test `> 90` is the same as `> .9 * 100`, i.e. you want 90% of 100. Given that, you could do the following:

```
Const itemCount As Integer = 125
For i As Integer = 0 To positions.Length - 1
    Dim p As Integer = rndItems.Next(itemCount)

    If p < .90 * itemCount Then
        positions(i) = p \ 15
    ElseIf p < .94 * itemCount Then
        positions(i) = 6
    ElseIf p < .98 * itemCount Then
        positions(i) = 7
    Else
        positions(i) = 8
    End If
Next
```

I don't work in VB, so hopefully I haven't made a language error, but this should give you the general idea at least. You might also want to add code to do some intelligent rounding if you want to be strict.

Comment: This produces the exact same distribution (except for some rounding). You basically scale `p` and compensate for this scale by also scaling the thresholds. So why scale in the first place?

Comment: You may be right. But I doubt that this is what the OP wants (that's why I asked for clarification in my comment).

Comment: thank you hatchet, this is good too and may use this later on. sorry that i did not make myself clear that i needed the 8 to not show up as much. i was really just trying to understand what my code was really doing so I could change the 8 percentage. Both you guys did great in answering my question and i thank you guys for that. :)